# In flink, how to traverse Iterable objects multiple times？

Tags: java, apache-flink

Flink use `Iterable` in some operater. I have the following question about this:
Why use Iterable instead of List? Is it because the iterative object may not be put into memory at once? If so,

1. what should I do when I need to put all the elements in Iterable into memory?
2. What should I do when I need to traverse twice?

Below is the detailed code. In the `apply` function, I first need to traverse the `iterable` to build a r-tree index. Then I need to traverse is again to query.

```
public class AllIndexRangeJoinProcess extends RichWindowFunction<Tuple2<Boolean, Point>, List<Point>, Long, TimeWindow> {

  private static final int RTREE_NODE_CAPACITY = 50;

  private double distance;
  private transient SpatialTreeIndex<Point> treeIndex;

  public AllIndexRangeJoinProcess(double distance) {
    this.distance = distance;
  }

  @Override
  public void open(Configuration parameters) throws Exception {
    treeIndex = new RTreeIndex<>(RTREE_NODE_CAPACITY);
  }

  @Override
  public void apply(Long aLong,
                    TimeWindow timeWindow,
                    Iterable<Tuple2<Boolean, Point>> iterable,
                    Collector<List<Point>> collector) throws Exception {
    // build index
    List<Point> points = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Tuple2<Boolean, Point> t : iterable) {
      points.add(t.f1);
      treeIndex.insert(t.f1);
    }
    // query
    for (Point p : points) {
      List<Point> bufferedPoints = new ArrayList<>();
      bufferedPoints.add(p);
      bufferedPoints.addAll(treeIndex.query(p.getBufferedEnvelope(distance)));
      collector.collect(bufferedPoints);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide more context? E.g. what type of Flink operator are you implementing, where you want to traverse the list twice?

Comment: Hello, I've add some details.

Comment: Is your window function running with a parallelism of 1? If not, then how are you partitioning your points so that each sub-task can run independently with its own SpatialTreeIndex?